# How to List all the files from google team drive using google drive api with node js

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

How to List all the files from google team drive using google drive api with node js.
what change should i make here to get all the files from team drive or shared drive ?

````
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
const credentials = require('./credentials.json');
const scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
  ];


const auth = new google.auth.JWT(
  credentials.client_email, null,
  credentials.private_key, scopes
);
const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });

drive.files.list({}, (err, res) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    const files = res.data.files;
    if (files.length) {
    files.map((file) => {
      console.log(file);
    });
    } else {
      console.log('No files found');
    }
  });```
````

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? You should be able to list the files if you have the correct credentials.

Comment: In this code it is only listing all the files from my personal drive and not the shared drive. How can i get it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list the files in a shared drive you must:

> Make a request to [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) and at the minimum set "includeTeamDriveItems" and "supportsTeamDrives" to true.

Try it in the API explorer by following [this link](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?apix_params=%7B%22includeTeamDriveItems%22%3Atrue%2C%22supportsTeamDrives%22%3Atrue%7D)